# iOS: How to check FIRUser emailVerified without asking user to login again

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

Let's say, the user has already logged in on the mobile device.  The user then uses a personal computer to do the email verification.

I am aware that the next time the user logs in, the emailVerified bool will be up to date.

But what if in the above, is there a way for app to request emailVerified property without asking user to log out and log in again?

Edit:

What function or method that you can use to request up to date user data without a login?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered there is this function for currentUser:

```
public func reloadWithCompletion(completion: FIRUserProfileChangeCallback?)
```